# Spawn Pokemon only in Pixelmon

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I have an Pixelmon server up and running. I know that `spawn-monsters = false` disable Pokemon from spawning, but enabling it spawns monsters like Creepers and Skeletons too. Is there an command that I'm missing?

I didn't change the `pixelmon.hocon` file from Pixelmon. This is my `server.properties`

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Mon Mar 22 23:15:32 UTC 2021
spawn-protection=16
max-tick-time=60000
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=1
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=100
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
max-world-size=29999984
rcon.port=25575
server-port=25565
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=true 
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
rcon.password=alypixelmon
generate-structures=true
online-mode=false
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
use-native-transport=true
prevent-proxy-connections=false
enable-rcon=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While changing the server difficulty comes with additional side effects, if your intention for the server is to focus specifically on pixelmon, you may want to **change the difficulty** to peaceful. This will disable the spawning of anything that is aggressive towards the player, but should not include pixelmon creatures.

Additionally, in the pixelmon configuration file, there is a setting called "allowVanillaMobs" which by default is supposed to be set to false, disallowing all vanilla mobs.

Two choices seem to be your best bet:

If you want to simply disallow vanilla *monsters* you should set the difficulty to 0 (Peaceful)

If you want to focus solely on pixelmon and forego survival, you should double check if allowVanillaMobs is set to false. I would recommend setting the difficulty to peaceful anyway, so hunger does not become an issue.